# Specific choice and permutations in Python

Tags: python, permutation

> I want to have something like this,Can anyone help me please?
>   `some_function([1,2],3):`
>      `print([1,1,1])`

```
`print([1,1,2])`
```

`print([1,2,1])`
   `print([2,1,1])`

`print([1,2,2])` 
   `print([2,1,2])`
    `print([2,2,1])`

```
`print([2,2,2])  `
```

Comment: Please try to explain further what you are asking, what you already have coded, and what error are you receiving. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm interpreting this question as "how do I write a function that I can give [1,2] and 3, and get back all the combinations of those elements with that length? e.g. (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)". You can do that with [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product([1,2], repeat=3))
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```

If, for whatever reason, you do not want to import a module in order to accomplish this, the documentation conveniently provides an implementation that requires only builtins:

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```